# Wo soll "aktualisiert" stehen?

Tags: verb, preposition, word-order

Im Internetangebot eines Hotels:

1. Das Animationsprogramm wird auf der Seite **aktualisiert** unter "Für Kinder".
2. Das Animationsprogramm wird auf der Seite unter "Für Kinder" **aktualisiert**.

Wo soll "aktualisiert" stehen und warum? 
Sind beide Varianten richtig oder ist eine Variante zu umgangssprachlich?

Comment: Why do you feel "aktualisiert" should stay before "Für Kinder", but after "auf der Seite"?

Comment: Es ist mir unklar, was der Satz überhaupt heißen soll. Meinst du *Das aktuelle Trickfilmprogramm findest du auf der Seite »Für Kinder«*?

Comment: *Animationsprogramm* ist im übrigen ein schlimmer falscher Freund. Das sind nämlich entweder Damen, die in Reizwäsche auf den Tischen tanzen, um die Herren zu animieren, oder irgendso ein paar billig vom Arbeiterstrich des Urlaubsortes weggefangene Blödiane, die einen dazu zwingen wollen, bei Trinkspielchen mit den Mitreisenden mitzumachen. Nicht selten geht es da wieder um die erstgenannte Animation, nur dass keine Profis dabei sind.

Comment: @Janka - Sehr gute Übertragung (des vermutlich eigentlich Gemeinten) in einen verwendbaren deutschen Satz.

Comment: Man kann die Frage als Korrekturanfrage deuten und schließen. Man könnte sie allerdings auch als Frage zum Thema Ausklammerung deuten und beantworten.

Comment: Ein weiteres Problem mit dem Satz (neben jenen, auf die Janka hingewiesen hat) ist: Was ist mit "Seite" gemeint? Ist eine Seite (*page*) gemeint? Oder ist eine *site* (Website) gemeint? Das ist jetzt nicht nur Pingeligkeit. Denn von der Antwort kann auch die Reihenfolge der Satzbestandteile abhängen,und darum ging es in der Frage ja eigentlich.

Comment: Im Hotel gibt es einen Spielclub für Kinder. In dem Spielclub führt eine Animateurin ein Animationsprogramm für sie durch. Die Informationen über das Programm werden auf der Website unter der Rubrik "Für Kinder" aktualisiert.

Comment: @Dan nach den Sätzen: "Herr X ist per E-Mail erreichbar unter:", "Herr X ist erreichbar unter der Telefonnummer:"                                                                         "Erreichbar" steht vor "unter", also "aktualisiert" soll auch vor "unter" stehen, oder?